# Consequences of Java 32bit on Win(any) 64bit?

Tags: java, vista64, jai

I am trying to install JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) 1.1.3 in my Vista 64 and it says that in order for it to be installed JDK 1.3 and up must be installed. The problem is that I have already installed the latest JDK for Win64 and it seems that it is not willing to work with it.
I would like to know if there are any severe consequences if I install JDK 32bit instead of the 64bit in Vista 64.
Thanks in advance for any advice on the subject!

John

Answer (score 1):

I have the 32-bit JDK (1.6.0_11) installed on Vista x64 and can report no ill effects so far (after 3 months of use).

Just remember it goes in **Program File (x86)** rather than in plain old **Program Files**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 64 bit Java version for Vista actually has some disadvantages, like no browser plugin (so applets will not work). It seems that the 64 bit Java only makes sense if you really need the 64 bit capability, for normal users the intended version is still the 32 bit one.

Edit: Sun has now released 64 bit versions of the browser plugin and webstart.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that using a 32-bit version instead of a 64-bit will make any difference unless your library uses 32-bit shared libraries. (and doesn't have a 64-bit version)